# GridFS using Mongo ODM not working

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony1, doctrine-odm

I have a User document that needs to have multiple pictures for that document using GridFS. I am unable to save the files using GridFS.

Here is my User Document:

```
namespace Main\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 *@MongoDB\Document(db="mydb", collection="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;


    /** @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Asset") */
    public $assets = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->assets = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


     /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * Add assets
     *
     * @param Main\ClassifiedBundle\Document\Asset $assets
     */
    public function addAsset(\Main\ClassifiedBundle\Document\Asset $asset)
    {
        $this->assets[] = $asset;
    }

    /**
     * Get assets
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $assets
     */
    public function getAsset()
    {
        return $this->assets;
    }

}
```

Here is my Asset file:

```
namespace Main\UserBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;


/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
    class Asset
    {
         /**
         * @MongoDB\Id
         */
        public $id;


    /** @MongoDB\Field */
    public $name;

    /** @MongoDB\File */
    public $file;

    /** @MongoDB\Field */
    public $uploadDate;

    /** @MongoDB\Field */
    public $length;

    /** @MongoDB\Field */
    public $chunkSize;

    /** @MongoDB\Field */
    public $md5;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

}
```

Now in my controller I am trying to do the following:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $user = $dm->getRepository('MainUserBundle:User')
    ->find(1); //I already have a user document with id 1

    $asset = new Asset();
    $asset->setName('Test image');
    $asset->setFile($uploadedFile->getPathname()); //I have verified that this is a valid image
   $user->addAsset($asset);

   var_dump($user);

  $dm->persist($user);
    $dm->flush();
```

The error I see in logs is:

```
MongoException: zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes? (uncaught exception)
```

I get that at the following location:

```
myapp.com/vendor/doctrine-mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Collection.php line 203
```

Also the document is not saved. What am I missing? I have followed all the steps that were on the mongoodm site. ??

Comment: Jini: Actually realized your syntax *should* work based on the current documentation .. so removed my answer.  Did you try with a single image first to confirm that works?  Perhaps a bug in the support for multiple embedded GridFS files.

Comment: yes I will now modify to try on single image and see. Thanks for taking the time to look and verify

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Please post your solution if you did.

Answer (score 0):

error in metadata

[MongoException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoexception.php)

> You tried to save "" as a key. You generally should not do this. "" can mess up subobject access and is used by MongoDB internally. However, if you really want, you can set mongo.allow_empty_keys to true in your php.ini file to override this sanity check. If you override this, it is highly recommended that you set error checking to strict to avoid string interpolation errors.

for example:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$gridfs = $m->selectDB('test')->getGridFS();

$metaData = array(
'' => 'value', // '' as key
);

$gridfs->storeUpload('pic', $metaData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's impossible to store GridFS files in embedded documents with current version of MongoDB ODM.

You can use @ReferenceMany as a workaround.